# "git send-email" in post-commit hook doesn't work with Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop, git-send-email

### Description

Hi, i would like to know if it's possible to not use git include in github desktop.

I explain :

In my project i have a hook in post-commit which send me mail with the command

> git send-email

When i commit with command line it works (commit and email) but with Github Desktop no (commit works but not email). I don't have an error or something just nothing happend except the commit.
If you ask, the hook is trigged by Github Desktop, i create text file in the hook to check that.

So i would like to know if i can change git repository used by Github Desktop or if i can add git send-email to git.

Thanks !

### Version

- GitHub Desktop: 1.5.1
- Operating system: windows 7 professional

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Have this line in post-commit `git send-email --to some@email.com --smtp-server yourserver.com --confirm never origin/master`
2. Commit something

#### Expected Behavior

Receive mail in some@email.com with last modifications.

#### Actual Behavior

If i commit with

> git commit -m "my message"

It works and i get the email.

But if i click on **Commit to master** in GithubDesktop, the commit works but i don't get the email.

### Additional Information

I think it's because Giithub Desktop has is own git and doesn't have `git send-email` command.

#### Logs

**Log with git bash :**

```
$ git commit -m "test"
OK. Log says:
Server: yourserver.com
MAIL FROM:<sylvain@berthelot.fr>
RCPT TO:<some@email.com>
From: Sylvain Berthelot <sylvain@berthelot.fr>
To: some@email.com
Subject: [PATCH] test
Date: Wed,  9 Jan 2019 09:47:15 +0100
Message-Id: <20190109084715.8424-1-sylvain@berthelot.fr>
X-Mailer: git-send-email 2.19.1.windows.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Result: 250
[master f01ed4e] test
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 delete mode 100644 Nouveau dossier/s.txt
```

**Log with Github Desktop :**

```
2019-01-09T15:24:47.572Z - info: [ui] Executing createCommit: git commit -F - (took 1.382s)
```